# how can I specify a c++ type in QML using qmlRegisterType?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I need use qmlRegisterType in c++ to define a commun type with QML. That's supposed to be simple but I have an error in the QML.
Here's the c++.

```cpp
QGuiApplication app(ai_argc, aipp_argv);

    qmlRegisterType<MiniModel>("miniModel", 1, 0, "MiniModel");//there it is !
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("..\\..\\..\\..\\Tools\\Qt\\5.12.0\\x64\\5.12.0\\msvc2017_64\\qml"));
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("../../Inc/miniModel/miniModel.qml")));

    return app.exec();
```

and here is the QML

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.5
import QtQuick.controls 2.5
import "..\\..\\x64\\Debug\\" miniModel 1.0 MiniModel//unknown component


ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 300
    height: 480
    visible: true
    property bool value: Minimodelqml.

    BackEnd {
        id: backend
    }

    TextField {
        text: backend.userName
        placeholderText: qsTr("User name")
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        onTextChanged: backend.userName = text
    }
}
```

I tried :

```
/*cpp*/qmlRegisterType<MiniModel>("miniModel", 1, 0, "MiniModel");
/*qml*/import miniModel 1.0 MiniModel //QML module not found
```

```
/*cpp*/qmlRegisterType<MiniModel>("anothertry.miniModel", 1, 0, "MiniModel");
/*cml*/import anothertry.miniModel 1.0//qml module not found
```

and some others... I'm new to QMl and don't know how to deal with it.

I'm not using a QtCreator project. It's a visual studio 2017 solution. Maybe the problem comes from there ?

edit : the code using the singleton works "fine"

Comment: How does the project structure look like? Is all the code in the same build object? The last two tries are supposed to work

Comment: No, everything is in separated folders.
TEST_VIEW4 contains a QML folder with a specific folder for this QML code. It contains a bin folder with the exe file and batch launchers, an include folder with the headers, a source folder with the source files and the moc file (cpp). and another folder with the obj files.

Later, the class for the communication will be stored in a dll

Comment: this is very alarming `engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("../../Inc/miniModel/miniModel.qml")));` use `qrc:/` as mentioned below in @mohabouje 's answer. That could be causing issues finding your modules.

Comment: Try adding another call to `engine.addImportPath` which points to the folder that your qml's are in. If that works, you might want to check if the qml are actually compiled into the project (qrc also needs some compilation operation, maybe you missed that?)

Comment: I added the engine.addImportpath and it didn't change. I'm a bit lost about qrc. isn't it a file made by QtCreator which specify the folder architecture ? because I'm using Visual Studio, not QtCreator.

Answer (score 0):

Just `import miniModel 1.0` in `.qml` should work

```
/*cpp*/qmlRegisterType<MiniModel>("miniModel", 1, 0, "MiniModel");
/*qml*/import miniModel 1.0
```

Comment: That's exactly the point. It's not. I'm sorry, I forgot to tell you that I tried the correct way to do before doing all these strange ways...

Comment: @QuentinGirault try with a simpler project then, you must be doing something weird.

Comment: /*I did (a new project in my solution, not too simple, but simpler) and posted the results here. i added it in the topic, the last simple code I tried is the one about the singleton. i missed that with qmlRegistertype we have to instanciate the object in the QML. I didn't, and can't do that anyway*/

Answer (score 0):

Those are some of the frequent steps I do follow to expose C++ classes to the QML engine.

Let's start by declaring some constants:

```
struct package_manager {
    static constexpr auto package_name = "com.mohabouje.package";
    static constexpr auto package_version_major = 0;
    static constexpr auto package_version_minor = 1;
}
```

Then create your Qt Object, and expose the properties to the [QML engine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html):

```
class MyObject : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(double awesome READ awesome WRITE setAwesome NOTIFY awesomeChanged)
public:
    // ...
    double awesome();
    void setAwesome(double);
signals:
    void awesomeChanged(double);
};
```

In your main, then do:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<MyObject>(package_manager::package_name,
        package_manager::package_version_major,
        package_manager::package_version_minor, "MyObject");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
```

And your `main.qml` becomes:

```
import com.mohabouje.pacakge 0.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 300
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        MyObject {
            awesome: 25
        }
    }

}
```

See this [tutorial](https://felgo.com/cross-platform-development/how-to-expose-a-qt-cpp-class-with-signals-and-slots-to-qml) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much but my problem is that I'm stuck to the very first step. When I call "import The.Exact.Thing.Written 1.0" QML tells me "QML module not found (The.Exact.Thing.Written).

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue just now, turns out my mistake was that I called `qmlRegisterType()` after `QQuickView.setSource()`

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the answer posted by mohabouje, the class you defined, such as `MiniModel`, is located in a header file; let's suppose this header file is named `minimodel.h`, and your project file is named `myproject.pro`;

in that case you need to edit `myproject.pro` and add `minimodel.h` to the `HEADERS` section like this:

```
HEADERS += \
    minimodel.h
```

then, in main.qml, the `import MiniModel 1.0` should work